# Reading a JSON Message with an extra Curly Bracket at the end Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, db2

So I am new to python and I am currently having an issue with reading a JSON message and placing it in an object so I can parse its data.  The json message exists inside a column in a DB2 database and I extracted it and the rest of the row into a panda dataframe.  It hen tried isolating the json message into a object so I can then go into it and parse the data I need from it to insert it into another DB table.  But every time I try to use json.loads() it gives a JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end).  I printed the message and found an extra curly bracket at the end that shouldn't be there.  I tried to use trunicate but I just got another error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Example Row I am Selecting:

```
                    INSERT_TS                  MESSAGE_TX
0  2020-06-17 00:41:36.737369  {"ftcId":XXXX,"nbId":XXXX,"Id":XXXXX...
```

Code I am using:

```
conn = ibm_db.connect(db,"","")
pconn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(conn)

bom53rows = pd.read_sql(query, pconn)
df = pd.DataFrame(bom53rows)

print(df[["MESSAGE_TX"]])

policyMessage = df.at[0, 'MESSAGE_TX']
policyMessage.rstrip()

bom03Message = json.loads(policyMessage)
```

Comment: I assume that using `loads` on `df[["MESSAGE_TX"]]) did not work?

Comment: How about : `df['MESSAGE_TX'] = df['MESSAGE_TX'].apply(lambda x: x.rstrip()[:-1])`

Comment: Yeah.  That is where the error keeps happening.  When I try to run loads on 'MESSAGE_TX' I get the JSON Decode Error "Extra Data"

Also I tried the code you suggested and that seems to have cleaned up the extra curly bracket.  Thanks for helping me with that.  But do you know why there was an extra curly bracket at the end at all?  Anyway to prevent it from happening in the first place?